# How to implement dependency injection from console project?

Tags: c#

I have 2 projects in C# .NET 6: Web Api project and Console project.

How the Console project can call the service in Web Api project with dependency injection?

In Web Api project, I have an interface class and concrete class.

```
public interface IMyService
{
    Task Method1();
}

public class MyService : IMyService
{
    public async Task Method1(){
       //code removed for brevity
    }
}
```

and in `Program.cs`, I registered the service for Dependency Injection.

```
builder.Services.AddScoped<IMyService, MyService>();
```

Then in my Console project, I have `ConsoleApp.cs`

```
public class ConsoleApp
{
    private readonly IMyService _myService;

    public ConsoleApp(IMyService myService)
    {
        _myService = myService;
    }

    public void Run()
    {
       //code removed for brevity
    }
}
```

and in `Program.cs`

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Services.AddScoped<IMyService, MyService>();

var serviceProvider = new ServiceCollection()
    .AddScoped<ConsoleApp>()
.BuildServiceProvider();

using (var scope = serviceProvider.CreateScope())
{
    var app = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<ConsoleApp>();
    app.Run();
}
```

But, it breaks at `var app = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<ConsoleApp>();` with error mesage

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'Unable to resolve service for type
> 'xxx.Api.Services.ISMyService' while attempting to activate

Added solution from Michał Turczyn

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using var host = CreateHostBuilder(args).Build();

        //host.Run();
        using var scope = host.Services.CreateScope();
        var serviceProvider = scope.ServiceProvider;
        var consoleApp = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<ConsoleApp>();
        consoleApp.Run();
    }

    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureServices((context, services) =>
            {
                services.AddScoped<IMyService, MyService>();                                        
                services.AddScoped<IConsoleApp, ConsoleApp>();                                        
            });
}
```

But hit error at `var consoleApp = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<ConsoleApp>();`

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'No service for type
> 'xxx.ConsoleApp' has been registered.'

Comment: also register the service <IMyService>

Comment: also if service <MyService> has any dependency on the web API project that cannot run on the Console Application you should consider using the same Interface but write a different platform-specific code for the console application.

Comment: @kyenry, you mean Console project also should register the service? Where should I put the code?

Comment: @kyenry, I tried but still the same error. I have updated my code.

Comment: var serviceProvider = new ServiceCollection()
    .AddScoped<ConsoleApp>()
    .Addscoped<IMyService, MyService>()
.BuildServiceProvider();

Comment: Why are you using `WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);` for a console project? `WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);` is for ASP.NET Core...

Comment: `var serviceProvider = new ServiceCollection()` <-- Don't do this. Instead you should be using the DI features of `IHost` from `HostBuilder`: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.hosting.hostbuilder?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0

Comment: `using (var scope = serviceProvider.CreateScope())` <-- This is also unnecessary. The lifetime of your `scope` is the same as your root DI container. DI scopes are intended for sub-lifetimes (such as the (short) lifetime of a HTTP request within a (long-life'd) web-server process.

Comment: _"How the Console project can call the service in Web Api project with dependency injection?"_ - by using `HttpClient`. I don't think it's appropriate to try to use ASP.NET Core "in-process" - I'm not sure it's even possible at all (excepting integration test projects, ofc).

Comment: oh ya using `HttpClient` is for sure possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args)` is meant for web applicaiton and returns `WebApplicationBuilder`

You could achieve desired result by using `Host` from `Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting` namespace.

First declare the method

```
static IHost CreateHost() => Host.CreateDefaultBuilder()
        .ConfigureServices((context, services) =>
        {
            // Register necessary services, here some sample services.
            services
                .AddSingleton<INumberService, NumberService>()
                .AddSingleton<INumberRepository, NumberRepository>()
                .Configure<NumberConfig>(context.Configuration.GetSection("Number"));
        })
        .Build();
```

and then use it like:

```
var host = CreateHost();
```

Now you can resolve your services using `host.Services` object with `GetService` or other methods.

[C# fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/0QA7go)

Comment: I tried your solution but hit error. I have updated my original post.

Comment: I added fiddle with working code. I can't reproduce your error.

Comment: I saw what's wrong with my code already. I didn't resolve using interface. Thanks, it works now.